# i cannot seem to get a route to work when using models and controllers in express

Tags: express, routes

I am trying to set up a route using models and controller. I can get the basic `/` route to work but when i try to add `/config`. it does not work

**app.js**

```
var createError = require("http-errors");
var express = require("express");
var path = require("path");
var cors = require("cors");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");

var indexRouter = require("./routes/index");
var configRouter = require("./routes/config");

var app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "public")));


app.use("/", indexRouter);
app.use("/config", configRouter);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  next(createError(404));
});

app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get("env") === "development" ? err : {};

  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({ error: err.message });
});

module.exports = app;
```

**appController.js**

```
var Configuration = require("../model/configuration.js");

exports.list_all_config = function(req, res) {
  console.log(req);
  console.log(res);
  Configuration.getAllConfig(function(err, configuration) {
    console.log("controller");
    if (err) res.send(err);
    console.log("res", configuration);
    res.send(configuration);
  });
};

exports.read_a_config = function(req, res) {
  Configuration.getConfigurationById(req.params.configurationId, function(
    err,
    configuration
  ) {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    res.json(configuration);
  });
};
```

model

```
    //var sql = require('../lib/db.js');

    //Configuration object constructor
    var Configuration = function(configuration) {
      this.configuration = configuration.configuration;
      this.url = configuration.url;
      this.interval = configuration.interval;
    };

    Configuration.getConfigurationById = function(configurationId, result) {
      console.log("getConfigurationById");

      result(null, []);
    };

module.exports = Configuration;
```

**routes/config**

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();

var actions = require("../controller/appController");

router.get("/config", actions.list_all_config);

router.get("/config/:id", actions.read_a_config);

module.exports = router;
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/newsnow-u9eyv

if i put config routes in index file it works. but separately they do not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at my example.

https://codesandbox.io/embed/newsnow-uwvhi

You can add in index.js, so every route which is defined in config.js is reachable by localhost/config/

```
router.use("/config", require("./config"));
```

and in config.js

```
router.get("/", function(req, res, next) {
  console.log("Config");
  actions.list_all_config();
});
```

Comment: Are you saying to include all the route files in in `routes/index.js`? so its not possible to do this in `app.js`?

Comment: you can include it where you want. i create a folder named api, where a index-file is located. in this index-file i create the routes. For me it seems to be really clear and not that big mess. its also easier to include some middleware like auth-contoller.